# How to print the results of a SQLite query in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

I'm trying to print the results of this SQLite query to check whether it has stored the data within the database. At the moment it just prints None. Is there a way to open the database in a program like Microsoft Word or LibreOffice. Just to see whether it has saved the content into the database.

```
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3 as lite
import sys


class GUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)

    self.var = tk.StringVar()
    entry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.var)
    entry.pack()

    btn = tk.Button(self, text='read', command=self.read_entry)
    btn.pack()

    btn = tk.Button(self, text='write', command=self.write_entry)
    btn.pack()

def read_entry(self):
    #print(self.var.get())

def write_entry(self):
    self.var.set(self.var.get())
    con = lite.connect('RandomThings.db')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE jetfighter(Name TEXT)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO jetfighter VALUES (?)", (self.var.get(),))
    #con.commit()
    print (cur.fetchone())
    cur.close()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('200x200')
    win = GUI(root)
    win.pack()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thank you for helping me with my problem.

Comment: You don't seem to be making any queries. You just do an insert.

Answer (score 4):

Only `SELECT` queries have row sets.<sup>1</sup> So, if you want to see the row you just inserted, you need to `SELECT` that row.

One way to select exactly the row you just inserted is by using the `rowid` pseudo-column. This column has unique values that are automatically generated by the database, and every `INSERT` statement updates a [`lastrowid`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.lastrowid) property on the cursor. So:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO jetfighter VALUES (?)", (self.var.get(),))
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM jetfighter WHERE rowid=?", (cur.lastrowid,))
print(cur.fetchone())
```

This will print out something like:

```
('Starfighter F-104G',)
```

Answer (score 2):

Fetchone will only produce something if it follows a query.  After the INSERT, add

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM jetfighter")
print(cur.fetchone())
```