# Sqlite3 Python problem with wrong select output

Tags: python, sqlite

This is my code:

```
firstName = cursor.execute("SELECT firstName FROM students WHERE id = %s" % idRemove)
print(firstName)
```

And this is what i get in return:

```
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x00E88C20>
```

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50613392/how-to-print-the-results-of-a-sqlite-query-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function return a cursor object.

```
print(firstName.fetchone())
```

Comment: Yeah it works thank you! The result is: ('Lord',) But is there a option to remove the brackets and commas?

Comment: `print(firstName.fetchone()[0])`